# Optimizing post backs in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I am looking for a way to speed up post backs in asp.net. My issue here is that I have a decent amount of items displayed in a telerik RadGrid (a few hundred or so). Each of these items has a detail table. Each parent item and its items in its detail table have checkboxes. When the parent item's checkbox is clicked, it performs a postback and checks or unchecks all of its detail table's items. When I do this, I'm getting about a 1-2 second delay.

A couple limitations:

-Has to be performed server-side: My customer would prefer to keep client-side scripting at a minimum.
-Paging is not an option

There are only a couple things I can think of that would cause a performance hit:

-ViewState size: Although I'm not explicitly storing any values in the viewstate, I think my main issue is the number of items I'm displaying in my grid.
-Hits to the database: When the postback is performed, (aside from membership queries and other business logic) there are no additional calls to the database.

What other options do I have to speed up my postbacks?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that all of my controls are already ajaxified using Telerik's RadAjaxManagerProxy. I have them wrapped in a Panel called `pnlContainer`, and I'm doing the following:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="RadAjaxManagerProxy1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="pnlContainer">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlContainer" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>
```

Maybe there's a better approach?

Comment: Just a thought... Use Ajax so the postbacks are asynchronous, and do only partial page updates.  Sure Ajax is ***technically***  client-side but let's face it, a lot of "server side" stuff in ASP.NET results in a lot of auto-generated javascript.  Using the ScriptManager and UpdatePanels to Ajax-Enable your page is no differnt.

Comment: Do you need the postback? Or could you do what you need to in a client-side script instead?

Comment: Keep in mind that network latency may also be a problem that you have little or no control over. If the connection is slow, postbacks will also suffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following items if you have a big postback happening:

- If you have deep control hierarchy (many levels of controls) your IDs will take up a lot of space since each child control's ID is a concatenation of all its parents. Therefore your control IDs should be as small as possible.
- When not necessary, dont use .NET controls. For example, if you have a static label, dont use asp:Label but plain SPAN tag.
- Use UpdatePanels with ChildrenAsTriggers=true and UpdateMode=Conditional
- Minify your javascript and CSS files.
- Disable viewstate on items that dont need it.
- Enable compression on web server

Answer (score 1):

Try [UpdatePanels](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax). You can post back only part of the page that needs it, instead of reprocessing the whole page.